# Ada: Why exactly is ""A" .. "F"" not discrete?

Tags: arrays, types, range, ada

### Program Text

```
type T is array ("A" .. "F") of Integer;
```

### Compiler Console Output

```
hello.adb:4:22: discrete type required for range
```

### Question

If my understanding is correct, clause 9 from [chapter 3.6](http://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/05rm/html/RM-3-6.html) of the Ada reference manual is the reason for the compiler raising an compilation error:

> Each index_subtype_definition or discrete_subtype_definition in an array_type_definition defines an index subtype; its type (the index type) shall be discrete.

**Hence, why exactly is `"A" .. "F"` not `discrete`? What does `discrete` exactly mean?**

### Background info

The syntax requirements for array type definitions are quoted below. Source: [Ada Reference Manual](http://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/05rm/html/RM-3-6.html)

```
array_type_definition ::= unconstrained_array_definition | constrained_array_definition

constrained_array_definition ::= array (discrete_subtype_definition {, discrete_subtype_definition}) of component_definition

discrete_subtype_definition ::= discrete_subtype_indication | range

range ::=  range_attribute_reference | simple_expression .. simple_expression

simple_expression ::= [unary_adding_operator] term {binary_adding_operator term}

term ::= factor {multiplying_operator factor}

factor ::= primary [** primary] | abs primary | not primary

primary ::= numeric_literal | null | string_literal | aggregate | name | qualified_expression | allocator | (expression)
```

Comment: I think the last paragraph of [this chapter](http://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/05rm/html/RM-3-2.html) answers your question ("what is discrete type?") quite well. )

Comment: Note that a string is an array of characters. So `"A"` can also be written as `('A')`. Clearly that way you can see that it is not discrete.

Comment: @AlexisWilke: Actually, `"A"` can't be written as `('A')`. A positional aggregate can't have just one component. `('A')` is just a parenthesized expression. `"A"` can be written as `(1 => 'A')`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This:

```
"A" .. "F"
```

does satisfy the *syntax* of a `range`; it consists of a `simple_expression`, followed by `..`, followed by another `simple_expression`. So it's not a syntax error.

It's still invalid; specifically it's a *semantic* error. The syntax isn't the only thing that determines whether a chunk of code is valid or not. For example, `"foo" * 42` is a syntactically valid expression, but it's semantically invalid because there's no `*` operator for a string and an integer (unless you write your own).

A discrete type is either an integer type or an enumeration type. `Integer`, `Character`, and `Boolean` are examples of discrete types. Floating-point types, array types, pointer types, record types, and so forth are not discrete types, so expressions of those types can't be used in a range for a `discrete_subtype_indication`.

This:

```
type T is array ("A" .. "F") of Integer;
```

is probably supposed to be:

```
type T is array ('A' .. 'F') of Integer;
```

String literals are of type `String`, which is an array type. Character literals are of type `Character`, which is an enumeration type and therefore a discrete type.

You wrote in a comment on another answer:

> Unfortunately I'm unable to replace the string literals by character literals and recompile the code ...

If that's the case, it's quite unfortunate.  The code you've posted is simply invalid; it will not compile. Your only options are to modify it or not to use it.

Comment: A floating-point type can be used in a range, but not in a discrete_subtype_indication; ARM 3.6(8).

Answer (score 4):

Ermm ... I think it is trying to tell you that you can't use String literals to specify ranges.  You probably meant to use a character literal.

Reference:

- http://archive.adaic.com/standards/83lrm/html/lrm-02-05.html

---

> After all, the clauses quoted above are explicitely requiring string_literal to be used

You have misunderstood the Ada syntax specs.  Specifically, you have missed this production:

```
name ::= simple_name
   | character_literal  | operator_symbol
   | indexed_component  | slice
   | selected_component | attribute
```

Comment: Hmm.. Well, that would be interesting. Unfortunately I'm unable to replace the string literals by character literals and recompile the code; but if that would really be the reason, I wouldn't understand it. After all, the clauses quoted above are explicitely requiring `string_literal` to be used.

Comment: `"A" .. "F"` is simply incorrect code. If you're unable to change it, then I'm afraid you're out of luck. The quoted syntax clauses don't *require* a `string_literal`, they merely mean that a `string_literal` is *syntactically* valid in that context. The code doesn't have a syntax error, it has a *semantic* error. `"A"` is not of a discrete type. `'A'` is (it's of type `Character`).

Comment: Another way to think of the problem is that there are two rules in operation. Yes, strings do form literals, but array indexes are -also- supposed to be discrete types, which strings are not.